# Socket under bad network : Should I check connection state first or just send with retry mechanism?

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to build a socket application under a slow network. There's may be a chance that the network won't work (e.g. 10% percent of the requests will timeout).

I understand in some situations people will check the connection first by sending a one-byte data to the server, but in my case, I think the `checking` behavior is a waste here.

I am wondering that is it a good choice to just send my data to the server directly without any `status checking`. When it actually fails, then retry until it exceeds the retry limit.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Testing adds pointless complexity AFAICS. You still have to handle the case that the message fails even after the test passes so you may as well skip the test and just send the message.